# How to well close a lindenmayer curve from TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lindenmayer

I would like to know why the closed curve has that strange join at the start-end point.
I see that the rounded corners affect it but how to get a nice closed curve in this case?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Exemplo}{
\symbol{+}{\pgflsystemturnright}
\symbol{-}{\pgflsystemturnleft}
\rule{F -> F-F+F+F-F}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=3pt,scale=7,
      lindenmayer system={Exemplo, axiom=F--F--F, order=1, angle=120}, 
      rounded corners=5pt] lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick fix: Use `shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt` and replace `cycle` by `(5pt,0)`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, thanks. It could be a partial solution. Without  `cycle` the curve is no closed. Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you move already to the starting point with the last `F` atom. Then apparently tikz refuses to close the path properly because it is already closed. One way to fix this is to omit the last `F` atom. To this end, one could introduce a truncated rule,

```
\rule{G -> F-F+F+F-}
```

which differs from the `F` rule by the trailing `F`, or, more precisely, the lack thereof. The downside of this fix is that you have to be careful when increasing the order, but at least in this example it does work.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Exemplo}{
\symbol{+}{\pgflsystemturnright}
\symbol{-}{\pgflsystemturnleft}
\rule{F -> F-F+F+F-F}
\rule{G -> F-F+F+F-}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=3pt,scale=7,
      lindenmayer system={Exemplo, axiom=F--F--G, order=1, angle=120}, 
      rounded corners=5pt] lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively one could add a short stretch to allow tikz to properly close the path. This may be achieved with the `turn` key. (However, I am not sure why one needs `90` instead of `180`.) `\draw[line width=3pt,scale=7,
      lindenmayer system={Exemplo, axiom=F--F--F, order=1, angle=120}, 
      rounded corners=5pt] lindenmayer system -- ([turn]90:2pt) --cycle;`

Comment: Oh, very interesting. I didn't know that the curve is already closed. Also, I didn't know that we could mix rules in the `axiom` key. Very nice.